# Visual Studio 2012 unable to hit a breakpoint

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, breakpoints

I have code written in C#. I don't know why but Visual Studio 2012 is not hitting a break point in an of the solutions that I have. I have tried following solutions:

1. Deleting the .pdb files.
2. Clean, build again.
3. Restart Visual Studio/Computer.
4. Deleting the bin folder and build again.
5. Check the debug settings against someone's for whom its working.

I took the whole code again from our central server. But none of it is working. 
What could be the issue?

Comment: are there conditions on the breakpoint? can you set any breakpoint that gets hit or is only one the problem?

Comment: Have you tried just creating a new console application and testing a new breakpoint in that?

Comment: can you show the code and the place where you are inserting the break point ?

Comment: Have you verified that you are in fact debugging? What I mean is, could you have rebound your F5 key to start without debugging as an example? Have you tried using the Run->Debug menu item to make sure you are debugging and not just starting the program?

Comment: Yes I right click on the project -->debug..There are no conditions on the breakpoint. There is just one line that invokes a console.

Comment: I created a different project and I am able to debug for that. But, how come it is working for some solutions and not for others?

Comment: I have been working on these solutions for almost a year now and I never faced this issue. What could be the issue now?

Comment: I have tried it for all the project in 3 different solutions that have been in use for more than a year now..

Comment: Is that code ACTUALLY being hit is the question? It might be that your control flow is incorrect and the reason it is not breaking is because it is not being hit.

Comment: I have only 1 statement in the Main function.

Answer (score 3):

Verify that if you are building the code in **Release Mode** instead of **Debug mode**.
Check your **standard toolbar** and select **Debug**.

[image]

Comment: Given you can debug release mode applications why would changing the build config help?

Comment: Hi, Its working now. Apparently, a security update from the organization caused this issue. It was resolved. Anyways, thanks everyone..